# Using id to to create img src with jQuery (populating Bootstrap popover with img)

Tags: jquery, image, twitter-bootstrap, popover, populate

I have multiple Bootstrap popovers that need to contain an image that corresponds to the popover that's being clicked. I'm trying to get it set up where jQuery takes the id of the popover link and creates the img src using the id as the file name. I got it partially working - right now, it's creating the img src but it's only showing `asset/popprev-piruli.jpg` for all of the popovers instead of `asset/popprev-piruli.jpg`, `asset/popprev-italiano.jpg`, and `asset/popprev-salsa.jpg`...

HTML:

```
<a id="popprev-piruli" class="btn btn-link" rel="popover" data-content="" title="Preview of Piruli" >Preview</a>
<a id="popprev-italiano" class="btn btn-link" rel="popover" data-content="" title="Preview of Italiano" >Preview</a>
<a id="popprev-salsa" class="btn btn-link" rel="popover" data-content="" title="Preview of Salsa" >Preview</a>
```

jQuery:

```
$('a[id^="popprev"]').each(function(){
      imgurl = $(this).attr("id");
      var imagepopover = '<img src="/assets/'+imgurl+'.jpg" />';
      $('a[id^="popprev"]').popover({placement: 'bottom', content: imagepopover, html: true,});
     });
```

Comment: try this instead of $('a[id^="popprev"]').popover( ,  use this $(this).popover(

Comment: @LuisCardenas Hah! That did the trick. Thanks! :)